# Get only the first level children of type in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, children, getelementsbytagname

I have the following html structure:

```
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div><p>First tab content</p></div>
        <div><p>Second tab content</p></div>
        <div><p>Third tab content</p><br />
            <div class="myvideos">
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YWD2Z14w99Y"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and am using the following to get all the tab content divs:

```
$('.tab-content div').hide();
```

I want the jQuery function to only get the FIRST child  elements inside the "tab-content" 's. **CLARIFICATION - I want only the first Child divs one generation down, not their children**

ie. Note that the THIRD tab content has a second child div that is being picked up which I want to ignore. I've also tried the following but they don't seem to work:

```
 $('.tab-content > div').hide();

 $('.tab-content div:first-of-type').hide();
```

Is there any way to only get the first children divs? This can be with jQuery or Vanilla JS.

Comment: Use `:first` or `.first()`. Also read the jQuery documentation.

Comment: @John I need the first level children of type, not just the first child. This doesnt work: $('.tab-content div').first().hide();, nor does this $('.tab-content div:first').hide();

Comment: @John this is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jnapier84/sargqozu/3/ I'm trying to hide all tabs except the first, but have the youtube video (inside a child div) still visible, hence why I don't want to find ALL 'divs' in the chain, only the first children divs.

Comment: Elements inside a hidden element are hidden also. Sounds like what you are asking is not possible or you haven't explained this properly

Comment: @charlietfl The jsfiddle has tabs. On document load, all the tab <div>'s are selected and then hidden, and the first <div> then shown (to be the default active one). INSIDE one of these divs is another div, which I want to be ignored when the divs are selected. Only the FIRST LEVEL CHILDREN should be selected, not sub-children. See the tab with the iframe in it. It has a nested div I need to ignore. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: OK if I understand correctly you always want to see the video, so actually you need to ignore the parent of the iframe. Can't you just move it between the tabs and tab content?

Comment: @charlietfl sorry haha - I'm not explaining myself well. There is an outer parent div, containing 4 child divs. On page load I want to hide those child divs. However one of those divs has a GRANDCHILD div that is also included when I .hide(), because it's finding ALL divs under the outer div, not simply the FIRST LEVEL child divs. I want to select the children, not the grandchildren. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnapier84/sargqozu/5/ - how can I click tab 4 and have the video show? The video hides because it's in a grandchild div.

Comment: `$('.tab-content > div').hide();` does not hide the grand child...but it will be hidden when it's parent is. Giving your `<div>` a classname would sure help. Then target by class and most of this issue will go away

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
jQuery(".tab-content > div").first().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
        <div><p>First tab content</p></div>
        <div><p>Second tab content</p></div>
        <div><p>Third tab content</p><br />
            <div class="myvideos">
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YWD2Z14w99Y"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That does not work - see the jsfiddle. It won't hide the tab content: https://jsfiddle.net/jnapier84/sargqozu/4/

Comment: because you used show again on first element.. $('.tab-content div:first').show(); remove this link from your code at Line #7

Answer (score 1):

A Vanilla JS solution could look like this:

```
document.querySelector(".tab-content").children[0].style.visibility = "hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.tab-content div:first-child').hide();` is the solution

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - can you check in my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jnapier84/sargqozu/3/

Comment: You're trying to hide the element in line 3, but in line 5 it's showing again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this did solve it in the end:

```
$(".tab-content > div").hide();
```